# Select those rows only if corresponding column do not contains selected keywords

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

> dataframe

```
      result_title                      result_url

0   Top 100 Dentists in               url1
    Mau  Best Dental Clinics ..

1   Dentist 4 U - Dentists -          url2
    Book Appointment Onli...

2   Top 100 Dentists in Nalasopara    url3
    East, Mumbai - ...
```

reject_words = ['Top', 'Listings']

I want to select only those rows which should not contain reject_words in **result_title** column.
This is a small portion of my dataframe so there can be more keywords.

I tried reverse isin() but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
df = df[~df['result_title'].str.contains('|'.join(reject_words))]
```

Comment: Thankyou, it works, Does ' | '  working as OR operator here...?